# Selecting random records and not rendom records in same function in web2py

Tags: web2py

I am selecting random records from db like this:

```
def index():
    rows = db().select(db.test.ALL, limitby=(0, 5), orderby='<random>')
    return locals()
```

In the View:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{for row in rows:}}
{{=LI(A(row.things, _href=URL("other", args=row.id)))}}
{{pass}}
```

I want to add and display one record to this list from `things` that is not randomly selected. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a separate query to generate another `Rows` object and then [combine them](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Combining-rows):

```
rows = (db().select(db.test.ALL, limitby=(0, 5), orderby='<random>') |
        db(db.test.id == some_id).select())
```

Just reverse the order if you want the non-random record to come first instead of last.

Comment: thanks very much! Can you please explain how exactly I should do the part where you say the `some_id`?

Comment: That's just an example assuming you have the id of a particular record. The specifics depend on how you plan to identify the one non-random record (presumably there is some criterion for selecting that record).

Comment: thanks, yes, I have the id of the record I need but I am having trouble with the syntax for selecting that record. I want to identify the  non-random record I want but I guess I have to learn how to do that. I tried this to identify record id 5: `db(db.test.id == id(5)).select())` but of course, that doesn't work. Can you please show me how to select that record?

Comment: The record id is just an integer, so it should be `db.test.id == 5`. The `id()` function is a Python built-in function that returns an internal identifier for the object passed to it -- it has nothing to do with DAL record id's.